# Text appearing Small in High Resolution Android Phones

Tags: java, android, user-interface, textview, screen-resolution

I created a sample app in android. I tested it with HTC and everythig looks fine . But later when I run the program on Higher Resolution phone the test appears smaller. 
How  can I make the text appear same size even if the resolution changes in android?
Thanks

Comment: Basically what Graham Borland says. You may also want to look at this link for supporting multiple screen sizes / densities. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you're specifying the text size in **dp** (density-independent pixels) or **sp** (scaled pixels based on preferred font size), not **px** (pixels).